# Displaying buttons on Skype for Business application

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, microsoft-skype-bot

I am able to create and access the buttons on Skype (using HeroCard) and its working as per expectations.

The same code is expected to be deployed on Skype for Business as well.
As per the investigation done (see link - https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/SkypeForBusiness/  I should be able to access the buttons on skype for business as well). 
However the link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview says that buttons are not supported in Skype for business.
Can anyone clarify/assist over the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in channel inspector, buttons are down-rendered in SfB while natively rendered in Skype. In short, at the moment buttons can't be displayed in Skype for Business. I will check if there is a work around for this.

**Skype**
[image: Buttons in Skype]

**Skype for Business**
[image: Buttons in SfB]

Comment: Thanks @Fracisco , is there any possibility of adding HTML components which can be displayed in S4B. If that is supported, at least we could then look for creating buttons usIng that approach

Comment: I don't think so. We don't support straight html in most of the channels, but I will check it out and get back to you.